# Deeply nested recursive calculations cannot invoke a CLR Stored Procedure

Tags: ssas

I hit the above error message when running the below query:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[LEVEL INSTANCE none:Date:qk - lev00] AS
  'CASE WHEN IsEmpty([Dim Calendar].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue) OR [Dim Calendar].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue = null THEN null ELSE CDate([Dim Calendar].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue) END',
  SOLVE_ORDER = 127
SELECT
{[Measures].[AvgSelectedCount],
 [Measures].[AvgSelectedScore]} DIMENSION PROPERTIES [MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME],[MEMBER_CAPTION] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [Dim Calendar].[Year].[Year].AllMembers DIMENSION PROPERTIES [MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME],[MEMBER_CAPTION] ON ROWS
FROM [sqis]
WHERE
StripCalculatedMembers(CROSSJOIN(
  Filter(
    [Dim Calendar].[Date].[Date].AllMembers,
    DATEADD("d",-365,DATEADD("d",DATEDIFF("d",CDate(36526),NOW()),CDate(36526))) <= [Measures].[LEVEL INSTANCE none:Date:qk - lev00] AND [Measures].[LEVEL INSTANCE none:Date:qk - lev00] < DATEADD("d",1,DATEADD("d",DATEDIFF("d",CDate(36526),NOW()),CDate(36526)))),
  {[Dim Country Region Vendor].[Country].&[Italy]}))
```

> Query (14, 5) Execution of the managed stored procedure DATEADD failed
>   with the following error:
>   Microsoft::AnalysisServices::AdomdServer::AdomdException. Deeply
>   nested recursive calculations cannot invoke a CLR Stored Procedure.
>   Execution complete

What is the meaning of the error and is there anything that needs to be set for DimCalendar Date properties in SSAS?